# creating automatic backup when webdeploying

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, webdeploy

So what I want is that whenever i deploy from my dev-machine to the server-machine that an automatic backup of the current files for the site gets backuped.

I followed this guide for the configuration

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups

At the root-level in IIS at the server this is configured

[image: Configuration IIS]

Using PowerShell on the server and calling

.\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:backupManager -dest:backupManager=SiteName

will indeed create a backup of the site to the location D:\Websites\backups\SiteName_snapshots however no backup gets generated when I'm webdeploying from my dev-machine to the server.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for the publishing using a profile that is using an administrator account located at the targeted server.

According to this link:

[Setting up automatic backups in Web Deploy tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429371/setting-up-automatic-backups-in-web-deploy-tool)

This feature seems broken in VS2010, is this still the case for VS2012?

Comment: I have the same problem here...

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to set `EnableMSDeployBackup` to True in your *.pubxml file

```
   <Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
     ...
       <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
     ...
    </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by passing this parameter:

```
msbuild ... /p:EnableMSDeployBackup=true
```

Hope this helps